# Save Public Key Bytes as String using Bouncy Castle PGP

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I'm able to generate a public/private key pair, and encrypt/decrypt between them.  Now, I need to send a stringified version of the PGP public key to someone else, but I'm struggling with how best to do that.

To get my public key, I use:

```
inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
        PgpPublicKeyRingBundle pgpPub = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);

        foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
        {

            foreach (PgpPublicKey k in kRing.GetPublicKeys())
            {

                if (k.IsEncryptionKey)
                {

                    return k;

                }


            }


        }
```

I'm able to access `k`, which is an instance of the `PgpPublicKey` class.

The file that this pulls from is basically jibberish, it's the byte representation of the public key.  I need the string version that you would normally copy and paste between people.

How can I do that here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To encode a key in textual representation with Base64, just wrap the output stream in an `ArmoredOutputStream` before calling `PgpPublicKey.Encode`.

Your example extended to get the key as Base64-encoded string:

```
foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
{
    foreach (PgpPublicKey k in kRing.GetPublicKeys())
    {
        if (k.IsEncryptionKey)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            ArmoredOutputStream armoredStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(memStream);
            k.Encode(armoredStream);
            armoredStream.Close();

            string keyString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
            //...
        }
    }
}
```